# Prove that these are the eigenvalues of the Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the Linear Operator $f(x) \rightarrow f(ax+b)$ on the Space $\mathbb{R}[X]_n$

Show that the eigenvalues are $1,a,a^2,......,a^n$

There's a hint which says I should use the fact that $f(ax+b)=\lambda\;f(x) \implies \lambda = a^k$ where k is the degree of f(x)

I dont know how to prove this hint nor how to use it. Could someone help please?

Comment: Could you please give more details about the space and the linear operator? and what $a$ and $b$ are?

Comment: @mastrok I think I provided all of that? The linear operator is given in the question and a,b are arbitrary constants.

Comment: I am not familiar with your symbols or maybe I forgot what I learnt from my graduate algebra course :(  Do you mean $L$ as the linear operator and $Lf(x) = f(ax+b)$ ? What is $\mathbb{R}[X]_n$? I am not sure if I can answer your question, I just want to understand it first.

Comment: L is just as you described. $\mathbb{R}[X]_n$ is the vector space of polynomials  with degree <= n

Comment: I see. Then the problem maybe easy. For example, the first engeinfunction is a constant, and the degree $1$ engeinfunction is $m(x+ \frac{b}{a-1}) $ with eigenvalue $a$. It seems that you can explicitly construct all the eigenfunctions of particular degree.

Comment: In other words, the hint can be proven by construction.

Comment: I'm still stuck with answering the actual question though?

Comment: You are asked to find all $\lambda$ such that $Lf(x) = f(ax+b) =\lambda f(x)$. Since $f(x)$ is polynomial of degree $k\leq n$, you can verify that $f(ax+b) =\lambda f(x)$ means $\lambda =a^k$ by construction. You will find $n$ distinct eigenvalues, and the number of eigenvalues is already the dimension of the vector space which means you have found all of them.

Answer (score 2):

By explicit construction, you will find, if  $Lf(x) = f(ax+b) = \lambda f(x)$

then $f(x) = A \left((a-1)x+b\right)^k $ with $\lambda = a^k$, $k\leq n$, and $A$ is a non-zero constant.

You find $n$ eigenvalues, $1, a^2,...,a^n $, it is easy to prove that these are all the eigenvalues.